# Making friend connections as test user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm following the document here to automate creating test fb user accounts for development purposes. I'm using the facebook php library.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

Everything is working fine other than the "Making friend connections" section. I'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An access token is required to request this resource. thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\application\libraries\Facebook.php on line 453
```

I don't get this error when changing passwords or any of the other operations detailed in the document. Only this one.

I've tried supplying the access_token returned when you create a user but get the same result. e.g.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/100002663471192/friends/100002663471192?access_token=205766069471562|2.AQBvtLYGBZhz3q7D.3600.1310968800.0-100002663471192|LhlBBSANV6qg-ycKsMBWvbh0Te8
```

Comment: ok get a bit further with this. I'm sending the access token as a post var. I'm now getting "Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out. thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\application\libraries\Facebook.php on line 453"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. If you call the change password api then the access token is no longer valid and you need to get a new one.